# Testing if a Select Query found results

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi I'm new to PHP and would really appreciate if someone could tell me where I'm going wrong in this code. 
To put the code in context, I'm using the facebook to authenticate users and adding their signup details to my app database. 
In the following code intend to check if the user already exists in the database and if not add them. 
For some reason I can't test the `$result`

I've checked the query variables and they echo out without a problem

```
@ $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo 'Error: Could not connect to the database. Please try again later';
    exit;
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE oauth_provider = 'facebook' AND oauth_uid ='".$uid."'";

$result = $con->query($query);


if($result === FALSE){
    $insertquery = "INSERT INTO ('oauth_provider', 'oauth_uid', 'username') VALUES ('facebook', '".$uid."', '".$username."')";
    $result = $con->query($query);
}
```

I should probably add I have the code working using the older mysql approach. But I have read it is better to use the object-oriented mysqli approach.

Here's the old working code

```
if($session){
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
$select_db = mysql_select_db('database');

if(!$con || !$select_db){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else{
    echo "connected to database and table selected";
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE oauth_provider = 'facebook' AND oauth_uid = ". $user['id']);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

if(empty($result)){
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (oauth_provider, oauth_uid, username) VALUES ('facebook', {$user['id']}, '{$user['name']}')");
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " . mysql_insert_id());
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
}

}
```

Any help you can give me is appreciated.

Comment: if($result === FALSE){
could become if (!$result){

Comment: if ($result->num_rows() == 0) should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( $result instanceof mysqli_result && $result->num_rows==0)
```

break down:

```
$result instanceof mysqli_result
```

this is to ensure query go through and results return

```
$result->num_rows==0
```

this is to check the previous query matching any existing records

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`MySQLi_Result::num_rows` property](http://php.net/mysqli-result.num-rows) to get the number of rows of a [*MySQLi_Result* object](http://php.net/class.mysqli-result):

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // …
}
```

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli: willmcneilly is trying to port the old procedural code to MySQLi object oriented code. And `MySQLi_Result::num_rows` is always a number.

Comment: Right, i didn't noticed the first code: browsing by mobile phone.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done as simple as:

```
if($result)
{
// Do code when there are results
} else {
// Do code when there are no results
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as $result seems to come back as true no matter if it finds a record or not